# How can I replicate disabled appearance for a JCheckBox?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, checkbox

Take the following example code.  There is some bug in Swing which doesn't render disabled components as disabled if the component contains HTML.  Aside from reporting the issue, which I hope a colleague has already taken care of, is there some good way to work around the problem?

Whatever solution I take, I want it to be a global fix as opposed to something that needs to be hacked into every check box in the application.

I tried making a custom UI for the check box which calls `setForeground` before and after the painting, but it turns out that by calling `setForeground`, it fires an event which ultimately results in it calling `repaint()`, which calls the renderer, ...

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestCheckBoxes extends JFrame
{
    public TestCheckBoxes()
    {
        JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Enabled, plain text");
        JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox("<html><p>Enabled, HTML");
        JCheckBox checkBox3 = new JCheckBox("Disabled, plain text");
        checkBox3.setEnabled(false);
        JCheckBox checkBox4 = new JCheckBox("<html><p>Disabled, HTML");
        checkBox4.setEnabled(false);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

        for (JCheckBox checkBox : Arrays.asList(checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4))
        {
            checkBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            add(checkBox);
        }

        ((JComponent) getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                TestCheckBoxes frame = new TestCheckBoxes();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you want HTML there? As from the snippet above, I could not find any.

Comment: This was just a minimal example to replicate the issue.  The real application has a bold word in there to emphasise it as there are two rather similar looking check boxes side by side.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the checkbox and label into their own components and simply make a checkbox without a label. You could also maybe add them to a panel of their own and override the `setEnabled()` method of the panel to simply enable/disable the checkbox and change the label's color. Take this code snippet for example:

```
final JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
final JLabel label = new JLabel();
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        checkbox.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (enabled)
            label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        else
            label.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    }
};
panel.add(checkbox);
panel.add(label);
```

Note that `checkbox` and label must be final to use them in our panel's setEnabled()` method. Depending on how often you're inserting HTML into your checkboxes, you can always create your own component class to do this as well.

```
public class HTMLCheckBox extends JPanel {
    private JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Color disabledColor = Color.GRAY;
    private Color enabledColor = Color.BLACK;

    public HTMLCheckBox(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
        add(checkbox);
        add(label);
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return checkbox.isSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        checkbox.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (enabled)
            label.setForeground(enabledColor);
        else
            label.setForeground(disabledColor);
    }
}
```

And then add your own constructors and methods as you so desire. For example, override `setBackground()` to have it set the background for the panel, checkbox, and label. A `setText()` method to change the label text would probably also be convenient. Whatever you'd want it to do. And maybe even setters for `enabledColor` and `disabledColor` to allow you to change these at will.

Comment: Modifying renderers is also very useful, as in eugener's suggestion. I've come across problems where modifying the renderer made it display my HTML tags, though. It's a little tricky at times, but it does look a lot cleaner. :)

Comment: This solution sounds like it will require modifying every view in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start using  renderers instead of that. You can use HTML inside the renderer (such as JLabel) and your problem will go away by itself :)

More information is at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

Comment: Sadly, JCheckBox doesn't support a cell renderer.  Otherwise I would definitely use that, making a custom UI which replaces the default renderer.

Comment: What do you mean? I gave you the link on how to accomplish that.Just create your custom ComboBoxRendeder :) The renderer should be based ListCellRenderer. It definitely  works - I used it many times.

Comment: How do you suppose I would apply a combo box renderer to a check box?

Comment: Sorry :) For some stupid reason I thought we're talking about JComboBox.  As far as JCheckBox it is a well known long standing bug :(

Answer (score 0):

I gotta stop answering my own questions... must be something to do with time zones and getting time to think about it during sleep.

Somewhere else in the application...

```
UIManager.put("CheckBoxUI", "package.for.CustomisedWindowsCheckBoxUI");
```

And then this is the implementation, but this is still pretty hacky and it uses a utility method to generate the HTML colour string which is less than great for posting here.

Note that this only fixes it for Windows L&F.  Metal L&F has also been witnessed to have a problem but the solution is the same, just subclass BasicCheckBoxUI instead.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML;
import javax.swing.text.View;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsCheckBoxUI;

import com.blah.util.ColourUtils;

/**
 * Customisation of Windows check box UI to fix bugs.
 */
public class CustomisedWindowsCheckBoxUI extends WindowsCheckBoxUI {
    /**
     * Factory method called from Swing.
     *
     * @param b the check box.
     * @return the UI.
     */
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent b) {
        // TODO: Sun have an AppContext they use to store these once per app.
        //  Might be more sociable to use something like that.
        return new CustomisedWindowsCheckBoxUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        AbstractButton b = (AbstractButton) c;

        // Works around a bug in BasicButtonUI where a disabled button with HTML markup in the text will
        // not appear to be disabled.

        // TODO: Find a way to fix this globally for HTML rendering.  It seems odd that it isn't working.
        // I can see the code in BasicHTML.createHTMLView which uses the foreground colour, which is
        // obviously why setForeground() works as a workaround.

        if (b.getForeground() instanceof ColorUIResource) {
            View view = (View) c.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey);
            if (view != null) {
                // Ensure that we don't update the renderer if the value hasn't changed.
                String cachedHtmlFor = (String) c.getClientProperty("cachedHtmlFor");
                String key = String.format("%s:%s", c.isEnabled(), b.getText());
                if (!key.equals(cachedHtmlFor)) {
                    c.putClientProperty("cachedHtmlFor", key);
                    if (c.isEnabled()) {
                        BasicHTML.updateRenderer(c, b.getText());
                    } else {
                        BasicHTML.updateRenderer(c, String.format("<html><div style='color: %s'>%s",
                                                                  ColourUtils.toHtmlColour(b.getBackground().darker()),
                                                                  b.getText()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        super.paint(g, c);
    }
}
```