# Change Color of Disabled GUI Components in Java

Tags: java, swing

Guys I want to change the appearance of a disabled JRadioButton, JCheckBox

This code works well for ComboBox but when replaced by CheckBox or RadioButton no effect.

```
    UIManager.put("ComboBox.disabledForeground", Color.BLACK);
```

Also i want the Button to be non-editable. So dont suggest options like

```
    RadioButton.setEnabled(false);
```

[What I get vs What i Want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffLNE.png)

Comment: Not the beautifullest way, but you may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130650/how-can-i-replicate-disabled-appearance-for-a-jcheckbox

Answer (score 2):

> This code works well for ComboBox but when replaced by CheckBox or RadioButton no effect.

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.disabledForeground", Color.BLACK);
```

For a `JCheckBox` and `JRadioButton` you should be able to use:

```
UIManager.put("CheckBox.disabledText", Color.BLACK);
UIManager.put("RadioButton.disabledText", Color.BLACK);
```

Check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for all the default values of the UIManager.